Rocky Linux Repositories Disabled After Installing Clickhouse
I installed Clickhouse on a Rocky Linux server. After installation, updating the repositories gives me:
[root@localhost ~]# yum update
altinity_clickhouse                                    267  B/s | 833  B     00:03    
altinity_clickhouse-source                             233  B/s | 833  B     00:03    
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

Looks like all repositories - except for the ones for Clickhouse - have been disabled.
If I list all repositories, I get:
[root@localhost ~]# dnf repolist
repo id                    repo name
altinity_clickhouse        altinity_clickhouse
altinity_clickhouse-source altinity_clickhouse-source
appstream                  Rocky Linux 9 - AppStream
baseos                     Rocky Linux 9 - BaseOS
clickhouse-stable          ClickHouse - Stable Repository
crb                        Rocky Linux 9 - CRB
epel                       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64
epel-cisco-openh264        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
extras                     Rocky Linux 9 - Extras

However, if I look at each repo-file in /etc/yum.repos.d/, I get enabled=1 in the Clickhouse repositories and enabled=0 in all the others. This can't be right?

I'd like to think it's a bug - assuming you are not paying them for support, did you log an issue on their github site?

No, @symcbean, haven't done that yet. Will do.

Looks like it is the altinity installation script that interferes with the repos. So it is not directly ClikHouse. THe installation even disables the properClickhouse repository...
